# Save HTML file as utf-8 typescript on mobile device

Tags: angular, typescript, filesaver.js

I am using FileSaver js library to save a file as HTML on my angular site (https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

I have a lot of UTF-8 chars in the text and when I download the file from a browser on a computer, it works - but if I do the same from an android device the UTF-8 chars are not recognized.

My save file method is pretty straight forward:
    generateHTML(html, name) {

```
    var blob = new Blob([html], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
    saveAs(blob, name + '.html');
}
```

I have also tried changing the type to text/html without any luck...

How do I ensure that UTF-8 is used when the file is downloaded from any browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will work for me.

```
 String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName );
```